# Function that reformats and indents a string of an R code

Tags: r, indentation, auto-indent

In `RStudio` editor selecting a piece of code, say (1):

```
p = ggplot() +
geom_point(data = df, aes(gp, y)) +
geom_point(data = ds, aes(gp, mean), colour = 'red', size = 3) +
geom_errorbar(
    data = ds,
    aes(gp, mean, ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd),
    colour = 'red',
    width = 0.4
)
```

and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>  transforms the code and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> indents it in a more tidy way. The result looks like (2):

```
p = ggplot() +
geom_point(data = df, aes(gp, y)) +
geom_point(data = ds,
           aes(gp, mean),
           colour = 'red',
           size = 3) +
geom_errorbar(
    data = ds,
    aes(gp, mean, ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd),
    colour = 'red',
    width = 0.4
)
```

I have code (1) as a string:

```
my_code <- "p = ggplot() +
geom_point(data = df, aes(gp, y)) +
geom_point(data = ds, aes(gp, mean), colour = 'red', size = 3) +
geom_errorbar(
data = ds,
aes(gp, mean, ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd),
colour = 'red',
width = 0.4
)"
```

**How can I achieve the result of `my_code %>% some_function() %>% cat()` to look like code (2)?**

I tried `formatR::tidy_source(text = my_code)` but the result isn't as I expected.

Comment: My guess is that RStudio is not using `formatR`, in which case it doesn't surprise me that they are different. I think perhaps one of the larger problems is that with `ggplot2` pipelines, the `+` operator is typically followed by a newline, whereas normally it is not. (You might need to reference the [RStudio source code](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio) and/or an RStudio programmer to find their auto-indentation methods.)

Comment: try `rfmt::rfmt(text = my_code) %>% cat(sep="\n")` using https://github.com/google/rfmt